# python for-loop with 2 counters

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'd like to create a single for loop using 2 variables, instead of a for loop and an external variable.

Is there a way to do something unpacking tuples with range?

Here is what I have:

```
space = height
for h in range(height):
    # code using both h & space
```

Here is the code I'm trying to improve:

```
# Get positive integer between 1 - 8
while True:
    height = int(input("Height: "))
    if height > 0 and height < 9:
        break

space = height  # Control space count

# Build the pyramid
for h in range(height):
    print(" " * (space - 1),"#" * (h + 1), end="")
    print(" ", end="")
    print( "#" * (h + 1), " " * (space - 1), end="")
    space -= 1

    print()  # Get prompt on \n
```

Comment: Since ``space`` depends decreases as ``h`` increase, why don't you just compute the offset, e.g. as ``height - h -1``?

Comment: Isn't this a CS50 problem?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - Interesting, I see how that could work. Then there would be just one variable. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @agastya Yes, it is. I wanted to do something like C using 2 variables in a single loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a second `range` object (from `height` to `0`) and then [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate both ranges at once:

```
# Get positive integer between 1 - 8
while True:
    height = int(input("Height: "))
    if height > 0 and height < 9:
        break

# Build the pyramid
for h, space in zip(range(height), range(height, 0, -1)):
    print(" " * (space - 1),"#" * (h + 1), end="")
    print(" ", end="")
    print( "#" * (h + 1), " " * (space - 1), end="")

    print()  # Get prompt on \n
```

Comment: OK, 25 seconds faster than my same solution. Will delete it now.

Comment: I figured it should be possible to construct something like this, but I was not familiar with zip().  Thank you for pointing this out!